# Is there any difference between docker start and docker container start?

Tags: docker

I was wondering if there is any difference between

```
docker start <container name>
```

and

```
docker container start <container name>
```

I personally always use `docker container start` though, because that is the method that was suggested to run a stopped container. What would be the difference if I use `docker start` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between `docker container start` and `docker start`.

Over time, the docker cli has become more organized so that, for example, there are separate `docker container inspect` and `docker image inspect` commands.  Earlier, there was a single command that would do both depending on the arguments, which could be confusing.  There are a number of commands that are there for historic reasons (like `docker ps`, `docker inspect`, etc) that duplicate functionality that is now also available via subcommands of `docker container`, `docker image`, and so on.